# what code can i write to scrape a site and bring back results for all episodes of 5 seasons, including episode title

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

### what code can i write to *scrape* a site and bring back summary and episode title for all episodes of 5 seasons using BeautifulSoup?

```
import requests
 import bs4
 res= requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273855/episodes?season=4")
 soup =bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
 soup.select('.item_description')
 for i in soup.select('.item_description'):
           print(i.text)
```

Comment: you are going to need an outer loop where you add in the episode number to the end of a base string, then an inner loop possibly based on your current code to extract title and description for each episode (you might need a loop or a list comprehension for that)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through all the seasons and select the title/desc of each episode in that season.

## Code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

full_dict = {'Season': [], 'Episode Title': [], 'Episode Description': []}

for season in range(1, 6):
    res = requests.get(f"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273855/episodes?season={season}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    episodes = soup.find_all(class_='info')
    for episode in episodes:
        ep_title = episode.find('a', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})['title']
        ep_desc = episode.find('div', attrs={'itemprop': 'description'}).text.strip()
        full_dict['Season'].append(season)
        full_dict['Episode Title'].append(ep_title)
        full_dict['Episode Description'].append(ep_desc)

df = pd.DataFrame(full_dict)
print(df)
```

## Output

```
     Season  ...                                Episode Description
0         1  ...  Michael has been used to having his wife at ho...
1         1  ...  Janet and Michael find a tattoo parlor card in...
2         1  ...  When Michael and Jay realize that Jr. has been...
3         1  ...  Claire's trying to attract boys in school so s...
4         1  ...  Jr. gets an F in Algebra and forges it into an...
5         1  ...  Jr. has to get an A on his Algebra final. Mich...
6         1  ...  Jr. is having problems at school with a bully,...
7         1  ...  Jay wants Michael to quit watching TV and spen...
8         1  ...  Claire develops her first real crush on a boy,...
9         1  ...  Michael's brother Ken comes to visit and bring...
10        1  ...  Michael's accountant dies suddenly, making Mik...
11        2  ...  While Jay is away taking care of her mother wh...
12        2  ...  The pregnancy test was Charmaine's, who is thi...
13        2  ...  When Jay's away, the kids complain Michael is ...
14        2  ...  While Jay's visiting her mother, the kids tell...
15        2  ...  Jay returns from her mother's several pounds h...
16        2  ...  Michael overhears Claire on the phone making p...
17        2  ...  Michael's doctor wants him to undergo a colono...
18        2  ...  When Junior dares Claire to eat Michael's piec...
19        2  ...  Jay gets fired in front of the girls on "take ...
20        2  ...  Jay buys Jr. computer appliances (including a ...
21        2  ...  Michael accidentally kills Kady's hamster and ...
22        2  ...  Michael decides to teach the kids how to handl...
23        2  ...  Janet interrupts Michael's video game so they ...
24        2  ...  Michael is on a mission -- to get his notoriou...
25        2  ...  A family outing to see Paul Revere's house in ...
26        2  ...  Michael gets to the gas station and has to wai...
27        2  ...    The entire dinner is doomed from the beginning.
28        2  ...  Claire wants to go on her first date with Tony...
29        2  ...  Michael's parents come to visit him, but Micha...
..      ...  ...                                                ...
94        4  ...  During Family Night, Jay suggests they play a ...
95        4  ...  Jr. and Vanessa announce that they want to hav...
96        4  ...  Jr. and Vanessa announce that they want to hav...
97        5  ...  Know what this is about?\n Be the first one to...
98        5  ...  Michael can't focus on much else after learnin...
99        5  ...  Michael can't focus on much else after learnin...
100       5  ...  Even though Michael is the only one who can ge...
101       5  ...  Michael refuses to go to his high school reuni...
102       5  ...  Jr. is burnt out at being a father and Michael...
103       5  ...  Michael advises Jr. that it's ok to spend some...
104       5  ...  Jay enters the family into a karaoke contest u...
105       5  ...  At first, Michael is skeptical that Jay can be...
106       5  ...  Michael's enemy, Bobby Shaw tricks Jr. into si...
107       5  ...  Jr. and Vanessa's plan for a small, simple wed...
108       5  ...  After Michael treats Jay horribly during a dou...
109       5  ...  Vanessa buys Junior a foosball table. Michael ...
110       5  ...  Michael feels neglected because Jay is spendin...
111       5  ...  Jay announces that Saturday is Sweethearts Day...
112       5  ...  Michael reluctantly accompanies Jay on a medit...
113       5  ...  When the Kyles arrive at the Atlantis, Paradis...
114       5  ...  While at the Atlantis, Paradise Island resort ...
115       5  ...  Realizing that the garage is no longer a suita...
116       5  ...  The same day Michael realizes he can't fit int...
117       5  ...  When Jr. wins a national competition for his c...
118       5  ...  When Jay tells Michael that their love life wi...
119       5  ...  Under a time deadline to catch his flight, Mic...
120       5  ...  It's Jay's college graduation day and Michael ...
121       5  ...  With a lucrative bid from a large company offe...
122       5  ...  Michael, who is determined to make record time...
123       5  ...  Jay reads about a 67 year old woman giving bir...

[124 rows x 3 columns]
```